# Redirect /member/ to /member/user

Tags: users, redirect, wp-redirect

Is it possible if an user **is loggued** to redirect `/member/` to `/member/user` ? (User is the display_name)

If yes, how can I do this ?
Thank you ! :)

thanks to Jack, I tried to search on google "Wp-redirect". I write this :

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{  $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( is_page( 'membre' ) && is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/member/'.$user->display_name.'' ) );
        die;

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );


function my_page_template_redirect2()
{  $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( is_page( 'member' ) && !is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
        die;

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect2' );
```

I created a "blank" Member page in the admin section.

Is it a "good redirection" (perfomance, security, Google SEO...) or do I need to change everything :D ? Sorry, English isn't my native laguage.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into `template_redirect` action hook and redirect the users. I assume that you want to redirect the currently logged in user.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse314345_redirect_users' );
function wpse314345_redirect_users( $template ){
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        // Get the current user
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        // Redirect the user
        wp_safe_redirect( esc_url( site_url( 'member/' . $user->display_name) ) );
        exit();
    }

    return $template;
}
```

You can use other action hooks too, but make sure the action isn't too soon ( query not set up yet ) or too late ( header already sent ).

However this will redirect every request to that particular URL. You might want to also do additional checks, based on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jack ! I have a small problem. I put this code in functions.php, but I can't access anymor on the home of my Blog. It try to redirect to /member/user instead with an error on Firefox : "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I've already mentioned, if you don't set more conditionals you might get stuck in a redirect loop. Can you please explain your question a bit more? Need some technical details to update my answer. You can use the edit link under your question to add the extra details.

Comment: Thank You Jack, I edited my question with a working code. Can you review it ? Have a good day.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code is fine, but you don't need 2 different functions and actions. You can merge them and simply use 2 `if ( ... )` in the same function.